# Compare two lists to return a list with all elements as 0 except the ones which matched while keeping index?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I am a bit stuck on this:

```
a = [1,2,3,2,4,5]
b = [2,5]
```

I want to compare the two lists and generate a list with the same items as `a`, but with any items that don't occur in `b` set to 0. Valid outputs would be these:

```
c = [0,2,0,0,0,5]
# or
c = [0,0,0,2,0,5]
```

I would not know the number elements in either list beforehand.

I tried `for` loops but

```
['0' for x in a if x not in b]
```

It removes all instances of 2. Which I only want to remove once(it occurs once in `b` for the moment). I need to add a condition in the above `loop` to keep elements which match.

Comment: `[b.pop(b.index(x)) if x in b else 0 for x in a]`

Comment: @Ev.Kounis Yuck. List comprehension with side effects and quadratic complexity? No thanks. Can you post that as answer so I can downvote it?

Comment: If we set `a = [1, 2]` and `b = [1]`, would `c = [0, 1]` be a valid output?

Comment: @Aran-Fey, no it wouldn't be valid. I have to feed this list into a `df` column and match it with the previous columns value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following would work:

```
a = [1,2,3,2,4,5]
b = [2, 5]

output = []

for x in a:
    if x in b:
        b.remove(x)
        output.append(x)
    else:
        output.append(0)
```

or for a one-liner, using the fact that `b.remove(x)` returns `None`:

```
a = [1,2,3,2,4,5]
b = {2, 5}

output = [(b.remove(x) or x) if x in b else 0 for x in a]
```

Comment: Thank you. This works perfectly. Just wondering and waiting to see if it can be done in a simple one line.

Comment: The other post got deleted but seemed to use sets and then do the needful. The tuple thing is not really something I want to use.

Comment: Updated with a better one-liner

Answer (score 2):

If the elements in `b` are unique, this is best done with a [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-set), because sets allow very efficient membership testing:

```
a = [1,2,3,2,4,5]
b = {2, 5}  # make this a set

result = []
for num in a:
    # If this number occurs in b, remove it from b.
    # Otherwise, append a 0.
    if num in b:
        b.remove(num)
        result.append(num)
    else:
        result.append(0)

# result: [0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 5]
```

---

If `b` can contain duplicates, you can replace the set with a [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter), which represents a multiset:

```
import collections

a = [1,2,3,2,4,5]
b = collections.Counter([2, 2, 5])

result = []
for num in a:
    if b[num] > 0:
        b[num] -= 1
        result.append(num)
    else:
        result.append(0)

# result: [0, 2, 0, 2, 0, 5]
```

Comment: Nice one. "sets allow very efficient membership testing": is it because all the elements are hashable?

Comment: @JacquesGaudin Exactly. In the average case, a membership test in a set is just a hashing operation followed by a modulo to calculate an index, and then a check if the bucket at that index is empty. (All of that is `O(1)`.) In a list, you have to iterate over all the elements in the list until you find one that matches, which is `O(n)`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way using `set`. Downside is the `list` copy operation and initial `set` conversion. Upside is O(1) removal and lookup operations.

```
a = [1,2,3,2,4,5]
b = [2,5]

b_set = set(b)
c = a.copy()

for i in range(len(c)):
    if c[i] in b_set:
        b_set.remove(c[i])
    else:
        c[i] = 0

print(c)

[0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 5]
```